# How do you derive the formula $d= \frac {|a \times b| }{|a|}$ to find the shortest distance between 2 vectors?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Distance from point $P$ (not on $L$) to line $L$ (that passes through $Q$ and $R$) is $$d=\frac{|\vec{a}\times \vec{b}|}{|\vec{a}|}$$

where $\vec{a}=\vec{QR}$ and $\vec{b}=\vec{QP}$

Find the distance from the given point to the given line:

**(a)** $(4, 1, −2); x = 1 + t, y = 3 − 2t, z = 4 − 3t$

How do you derive the above formula to find the shortest distance between the point and the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Geometrically, the formula is saying $PH$ equals the area of the parallelogram divided by $QR$.

Comment: How about vector projection method? Is vector projection method applicable to this scenario as well?

Comment: Yes, you can actually do the following as well: (1) first cross $PQ$ and $QR$, let it be $V$, then cross $QR$ and $V$ to get the direction of $PH$. Then dot product $PQ$ with the normalized direction vector of $PH$. However this method is much slower as it looks..

Answer (score 0):

$d= \frac{|a \times b|}{|a|}=|bsin(\alpha)| $ where $\alpha$ is the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$.